# Starting tomcat in eclipse vs command line

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using tomcat 6 and when I start it from the command line the application it's running works fine, but when I start tomcat from eclipse (I added it as a server in eclipse) I get a 404 error when I try to run the application in my browser. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Please show your logs...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, when you reference an existing Tomcat instance in Eclipse, only its engine is been used. All already-deployed webapps in Tomcat's `/webapps` folder are **ignored**. You seem to expect that they are also accessible when you start Tomcat from inside Eclipse.

You need to configure the Tomcat server reference in Eclipse to set *Server Locations* to *Use Tomcat installation* instead of (default) *Use workspace metadata*. Double click the Tomcat server entry in *Servers* view to edit it.

[image]

This way, everything which is deployed to Tomcat, outside control of Eclipse, will also be available when you start Tomcat from inside Eclipse.